# Delete Row if Match found from another spreadsheet - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to delete any rows of data from spreadsheet 2 if a Match is found in spreadsheet 1.
In the image below (spreadsheet 1) we have **SKU A10114 & New Location J05A1**.

[image]

In the below Image(Spreadsheet 2) here you can see **SKU A10114 at Location J05A1** has 2 line entries.

So the code would delete both lines of A10114 at Location J05A1 ONLY

If A10114 had a different location it would not be deleted

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the row numbers and column letters of your sample Spreadsheet. And also, can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script?

Comment: Hi Tanaike この共有スプレッドシートのコードは私が必要とすることを行います。ただし、1つのスプレッドシートでのみ削除されるため、2つのスプレッドシートを確認する必要があります。移転・販売。コードは再配置を調べ、salesで一致するものを見つけて削除します

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQgymC39hSX1erqMa4Ic3m4IYy9GuMqMZ6wLYaXwTac/edit#gid=2048014007

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to delete rows in `Sales` sheet, when the values of columns "A" and "F" in `Relocation` sheet are included in the values of columns "A" and "B" in `Sales` sheet.

For this, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve the values from `Relocation` sheet and create an object for searching values.
2. Retrieve the values from `Sales` sheet and create an array for deleting the rows.
3. Delete rows.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  // 1. Retrieve the values from `Relocation` sheet and create an object for searching values.
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Relocation');
  const valuesSheet1 = sheet1.getRange("A1:J" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues()
  .reduce((o, [a,,,,,f]) => Object.assign(o, {[a + f]: true}), {});

  // 2. Retrieve the values from `Sales` sheet and create an array for deleting the rows.
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sales');
  const valuesSheet2 = sheet2.getRange("A2:B" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues()
  .reduce((ar, [a,b], i) => {
    if (valuesSheet1[a + b]) ar.push(i + 2);
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  
  // 3. Delete rows.
  valuesSheet2.forEach(r => sheet2.deleteRow(r));
}
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your script in your shared Spreadsheet, from the sheet names in the script, I thought that your script might not be related to this question. So I proposed above sample script.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)